# Reading "NA" values in a column in r through read.csv

Tags: r

I have a database with values in column as NA and I want R to read it as NA only but it does not read it correctly

command used
country_tmp <-read.csv(country,header = T )

Database
Country
NAME AGE GENDER working noofworkinghousrs
X1   22   F      Y      10
X2   33   M      Y      12
X3   23   F      N      NA

here NA is for notapplicable and I want to take count of NA but r is not reading anything as NA

Comment: Do you mean it's reading them as the string "NA" and you want them to be proper missing values, or do you mean it's reading them as missing values and you want it to just be the string "NA"?

Comment: Maybe the format (NA as string or missing value) is not the problem because in both cases it would be possible to count them.

Comment: I want it to be NA as string value but it is counting as missing value

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but in case anyone asks this question, like me before finding the answer

country_tmp <-read.csv(country,header = T, na.strings = "" )